# Can static member function of base class call its derived class object? (C++)

Tags: c++

Can static member function of base class call its derived class object?

Comment: what is meant by calling a derived class object? you mean a virtual function?

Comment: How does static member function getting reference to the derived object? Also is the method call public or private ? And is it virtual? Can you share some code

Comment: Could you tell us exactly what you mean here - call another static function in the derived object? Call back to a polymorphic function in the derived object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of `static` member-function as some non-member function. So yes. Whatever non-member function can do, `static` member-function can do the very same thing!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though there are two things to watch out for.

The first is forward-references. If the code to your static method is in the `.cpp` file, you should be able to safely #include the base and derived class headers.

```
<Base.h>
class Base
{
protected:
    Base();
public:
    virtual ~Base();

    static Base* Create();
};

<Derived.h>
#include "Base.h"
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int aParameterGoesHere);
};

<Base.cpp>
#include "Base.h"
#include "Derived.h"

Base::Base() { }
Base::~Base() { }

Base* Base::Create()
{
    return new Derived(42);
}
```

The second thing to watch for is that private/protected members of `Derived` are not accessible from `Base` unless they were declared as virtual members of `Base` or `Base` is declared a friend class of `Derived` (which is not unreasonable, considering the tight coupling):

```
<Derived.h>
#include "Base.h"
class Derived : public Base
{
    friend Base;
private:
    Derived(int aParameterGoesHere);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it can not call, because a static member function has no object assigned to it, therefore it has no its derived class object.

However, it is possible if you are using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), like this :

```
template< T >
struct base
{
  base()
  {
    T::foo();   // here calling a static method of derived class
  }
  virtual ~base(){}
};

struct A : base< A >
{
  virtual ~A(){}
  static void foo()
  {
    // do stuff
  }
};
```

Comment: VJo : why not use `virtual` function instead?

Comment: @Nawaz I don't understand your question. In a static method, you can not access this. If you want to use virtual instead of static for foo(), you would call foo in the base class, not in the derived.